# Leave Requests in Odoo 9 don't get sent to manager

Tags: odoo-9

In Odoo 8 when somebody put a leave request in a message got sent to their manager so they knew that something needed doing.  In Odoo 9, that doesn't appear to happen.  The Message appears in **Messages** under the **Email** settings in **Developer Mode**, but there are no **Recipients** or **Partners with Need Action**.  Anybody have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Have u check  the Outgoing mail server configuration setting ? Is it Working Fine or Not ?

Comment: Yes, the mail config is ok, so when a manager approves the holiday the requester is getting an email.

Comment: Have u find any Traceback from the terminal ?